# What is a default limit of Firestore query for getAll of firebaseAdmin and updated function for firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I used nodejs and i use firebase admin handle logic function.
This is my code:

```
  async getUsersByIds(ids) { 
  const refs = ids.map(id => firestore.doc(`users/${id}`))
    return await firestore.getAll(...refs)
  }
```

With ids for  uuid(firebase auto generate) document of user. I have 10.0000 ids from input by user.
When i receiver success data, i using it updated new field look like :

```
const users = await
getUsersByIds(req.body.ids);

await Promise.all(users.map(async user => {
    if (user.exists) {
        await handleLogicUpdateUser(user)
    } else {
        console.info('[INFO] Not exist user with id: ', user.id)
    }
}));

async function handleLogicUpdateUser(user) {

    await getUsersConnection().doc(user.id).update({
            somefield: someValue
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.info('[INFO]: Updated Success ' + user.id);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.warn('[WARN]:  Updated Error : ' + user.id + ' fail: ' + error);
        });

}
```

I have a question. When i query **firestore.getAll(...refs)** it can return 10.000 record for my function or not ? What number limit document return of function firestore.getAll
When i using forEach and updated , it can updated correct or it limit 1000 document in second  for function updated base with document.When i read document it limit 1000 document when updated. If my case bigger 1.000 it error or rollback ?

[https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices?fbclid=IwAR2FwNznzvmU9DBUGlg8dplgEUbX5J3H0BAylZuFTL2VRoyOkHIkXxYDrBI#realtime_updates](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices?fbclid=IwAR3Me3S0SxEAsm5DCkeli68_uaAy-ypmpip1d7CV-8_A-J551f8q_mcTlEo#realtime_updates)

What's number document limit when i updated for my function ? How to limit number updated when i using my function above ? Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation to the amount of records a function can return, that I'm aware of.

It's worth noting that if you are using the Free tier there is a limit of 50.000 document reads per days, more information  can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#:%7E:text=Document%20reads,50%2C000%20per%20day).
This limit disappears if you aren't using the Free tier there. However, there is a cost associated with document reads, you can check the prices [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#select-region).

You mentioned that you would like your function to return 10.000 records when you call it. I'm not aware of what your use case is but I strongly encourage you to check if implementing [query pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) would be a feasible option for you.
Querying all the data at once when you don't need to can cause slow queries, you can find an example about this issue in [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/08/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow.html#:%7E:text=Probably%20the%20most%20common%20explanation,the%20part%20that%27s%20running%20slowly.) in the Firebase blog.